# Qt C++ QMenuBar in Layout problem when scrolling

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am new to Qt and am having difficulties with scrollbars in QWidgets.
I have a layout in a widget and the layout contains a QMenuBar. The Scroll area is associated with the widget. The scroll works fine but when the user scrolls down the Menubar goes out of sight. Is there any way to keep the Menu at the top?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Hi @utdemir,

Thanks for quick reply.
Here is the snippit of the code with your suggestion of using QMainWindow. It produced the same results.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QMainWindow *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    main = new QWidget;       //Widget that contains the layout
    CreateMenu();
    scrollArea  = new QScrollArea;
    layout = new QVBoxLayout();

    //layout->setMenuBar(menuBar);
    this->setMenuBar(menuBar);
    this->resize(500,500);
    main->setLayout(layout);
    this->setCentralWidget(main);
    scrollArea->setWidget(this);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    scrollArea->show();

    this->show();
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example code? If you want one menubar per widget, you can use QMainWindow for your gui and use .setMenuBar method.

Comment: Move the QMenuBar out of the widget

Comment: @utdemir the snippit of the code is posted. QMainWindow produced the same results. Do you have any suggestions?   Thanks

Comment: @user844778, sorry I don't know C++ well, but I think scrollArea.setWidget(this) could be scrollArea.setWidget(main). But really I don't know.

Comment: @utdemir I tried that as well but the scrollArea->show() creates a new window containing the main widget. So it ends up being one window which is the QMainWindow containing the menubar and a separate window containing the scroll area which includes the layout.

Comment: @utdemir figured it out =D   this->setCentralWidget(main); should have been this->setCentralWidget(scrollArea); It works now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution to the problem.
Created a QMainWindow which contains the menu bar. Added a QWidget which contains the layout. The scroll area is associated to the QWidget. The central widget of the mainwindow is set to be the scroll area.

```
main->setLayout(layout);
this->setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
scrollArea->setWidget(main);
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
scrollArea->show();
this->show();
```

Thank you for your help @utdemir